# RDS Aurora - get number of bytes scanned by a query?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Is it possible to get the amount of bytes read by a query in aurora? If not at the query level, is it possible to have it at the table level?.

I've looked into performance insights, and the performance_schema tables, but they all seem to have data only for ROWS_SCANNED, not the amount of physical bytes. Metrics for I/O in performance insights also seem to be at the database level, not table.

Answer (score 1):

For all of InnoDB, see `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_%';`

There is a reason that the metrics are global, not at the database or table level -- the buffer_pool is a cache.  Each query depends on and interferes with every other query.  At least at the I/O level.

I dispute whether "bytes scanned" is relevant.  It seems like "rows touched" is more useful.  After I/O, accessing a row is the most costly task in performing a query.

Unfortunately, Innodb status values are aggregate statistics, so you need to run one query at a quiet time in order to get stats for a single statement.

Do this before and after your query, then take the differences.

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Innodb%read%';
```

Caution:  Some count rows, some count blocks, some count bytes.

Keep in mind that things like "bytes read from disk" will come in multiples of 16KB because of the blocking.  I don't think anything watches "bytes scanned".

Please describe further what you would like to do with the data if you could get it.  I may be able to give you a more focused answer.

I find that `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';` is very good for deciphering how much work happens for a single query.  And it is per-session (as well as global).

"Write" metrics usually refer to temp tables built to support complex `SELECTs`.